# Physics Problem: Falling Rocket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, free-fall

A rocket, of mass $M = 40kg$, falls vertically with a speed of $60 m/s = v_0$ and explodes in two fragments of the same mass when it's at $H=2km$ from the ground. Immediately after the explosion one of the two fragments moves at the speed of $80 m/s = v_1$ directed below. Determine the position $h$ of the centre of mass of the system after 10 seconds and the energy E generated by the explosion.

I have encountered this problem in my physics textbook, and I have written the conservation of momentum before and after the explosion as 
$$
Mv_0 = 2mv_0 = mv_1+mv_2
$$
which should be correct. I then obtain the speed $v_2 = 40m/s$
After ten seconds the speeds should be
\begin{gather*}
v_1f(10s) = v_1+gt = 80+10g\\
v_2f(10s) = v_2+gt = 40+10g\\
\end{gather*}
After that I have written the conservation of energy throughout the fall

$$
\frac{1}{2}2mv_0^2+2mgH = \frac{1}{2}m(v_1f^2+v_2f^2)+2mgh
$$

$h$ should be 910m from the solution offered by the textbook, but I get 889.592 which is not correct.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinetic energy of the rocket pieces may not be conserved in these circumstances (because of the energy from the explosion), but momentum definitely will be.

In fact, the explosion is a red-herring for the first part of the question.  The centre of mass will continue to move in the same way before and after the explosion.

The postion, $p$ of the centre of mass as a function of time is simply:

\begin{equation}p(t) = 2000m - 60m/s\cdot t - \frac{1}{2}gt^2\end{equation}

It doesn't matter whether there's one, two or more components.  Substituting in $t=10s$ [gives you the expected answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2000m%20-%2060m%2Fs*10s%20-%200.5*acceleration%20due%20to%20gravity*100s%5E2).

You can use your energy equation for before and after energy to determine how much energy was added to the system.  You correctly work out the velocities of the components (using conservation of momentum).  With the velocity and masses you can work out energy and see how it differs from the initial kinetic energy.